# Code coverage for REST calls using jacoco

Tags: rest, client, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using arquillian to test my REST endpoint. Here's a sample end point and test case that we are using.

**REST ENDPOINT**

```
@Path("/v1/example")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @EJB
    HelloWorldRemote helloWorldRemote;

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    public Response getSayHello(){
        String helloText = helloWorldRemote.sayHello();
        final Response  response = Response.ok(helloText).build();
        return response;
    }

    public String nonRESTSayHello(){
        return "SAY HELLO NONREST";
    }
}
```

**TEST CASE:**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class HelloWorldResourceTest {

    @Test
    @OperateOnDeployment("REST")
    public void testGetSayHello() {
        System.out.println("testGETSAYHELLO!!!!!");

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Invocation.Builder builder = client.target(
                "http://localhost:8080/CoverageTest/api/v1/example/hello")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = builder.get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());

    }

    /*
     * @Test 
     *  public void testNonRESTSayHello(){
     *      HelloWorldResource hwr=new HelloWorldResource(); 
     *      String str = hwr.nonRESTSayHello();
     *      assertEquals("SAY HELLO NONREST",str);
     * }
     */

}
```

I am separating REST and NONREST elements into separate shrinkwrap archives and deploy it to server and testing. The problem is I am not getting jacoco coverage for REST endpoints. If I uncomment testNonRESTSayHello(), It will show coverage for the class - only for the method : nonRESTSayHello() although both methods are getting executed. The difference is the rest endpoint is acalled via Invocation.Builder from testcase.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

While you could achieve coverage testing with Jacoco while 'black box' testing  (see [this page on how to use a java agent with tcp client/server](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html)), I'm wondering why you should do it. I mean, testing a rest service in a 'black box' fashion is just a way of testing the rest framework you are using along with your code. In this scenario I usually use mocks and test the rest services as plain methods, since this way the tests are (in my opinion) much easier  to read, maintain and (last but not least) faster to run.
Edit, to add an example :

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class HelloWorldResourceTest {

  @EJB
  HelloWorldResource helloService;

  @Test
  public void testGetSayHello() {
      Response response = helloService.getSayHello();
      assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
  }

}
```

Comment: I have already tried hooking the jacocoagent in jvm but doesn't seems to work. But I don't know how to do  it with tcp client/server. can you please help me on this?

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/LlqoJpuacak) can help you.

Comment: Can you please help me on setting up the client like in http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/java/ExecutionDataClient.java   Where should I implement this piece of code?

Comment: That looks like a separate client application, that you should execute while the coverage agent is running in order to extract coverage data via tcp and dump it to a file. I don't know if it's a working example or just a starting point. I'd tell you to compile it and run it as it is, and then see if it needs adjustment.

Comment: Sure I'll do and let you know

Comment: Hi @francesco foresti, I tried as per the thread. I am getting coverage for everything except for REST calls.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I am looking for an implementation for the same. If anyone has, please share. My application has a lot of REST calls and none of them are getting covered.